# I get an error while Solana Token Name Update

Tags: metaplex, web3.js, metadata

0

i am trying to name my token with metadata but i get this error always.

```
C:\Users\efeka\Desktop\img\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4546 throw new SendTransactionError( ^

SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x7 at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\efeka\Desktop\img\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4546:13) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\efeka\Desktop\img\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4505:20) at async Connection.sendTransaction (C:\Users\efeka\Desktop\img\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4493:12) at async Object.sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\Users\efeka\Desktop\img\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\util\send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:31:21) at async main (C:\Users\efeka\Desktop\img\name.ts:62:18) { logs: [

'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',

'Program log: Instruction: Update Metadata Accounts v2',

'Program log: Update Authority given does not match',

'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 5855 of 200000 compute units',

'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x7' ] }
```

I didnt create token now, i created my token before 1 year. I think i didnt authorize my token or wallet.

Comment: please format the description with code blocks to delineate commands and their output.  as is it is very difficult to read

Comment: i edited again.

Answer (score 1):

The error said that are you trying to do something to the token, using a wallet that is not the updateAuthority of the token. Basically you are trying to modify the token using a wallet that is different that the one used to create the token (I assume in this case you didnt change the authority of the token at any time, so you should use the same wallet that you used to create the token to udpate the token)

Comment: Thanks, i think i am using the same wallet. How can i check this?

Comment: You can check who the authority is on any explorer, like solscan.

Comment: For the NFT check the update authority field (you can check from solscan or explorer) and verify its the same address with which you are trying to update the metadata on

Comment: Yes, i checked in solana explorer "metadata"
 the "updateAuthority":string"AqH29mZfQFgRpfwaPoTMWSKJ5kqauoc1FwVBRksZyQrt" is this.

This is not mine, how can i change it?

Comment: You need access to the updateAuthority wallet in order to change it. If you dont have access to that wallet just create a new SPL token with the wallet that are you using rn

Comment: I cant acces the updateAuthority wallet because it isnt my wallet, i didnt use it before.

And i checked it, this wallet has lots of tokens, i searched random token name and her wallet is also visible at this address.

My tokens are important, i cant create new token. I am already using my tokens.

Comment: How you created the token then one year ago?

Answer (score 0):

It was metaplex who changed your update authority,,, https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/issues/1055#issuecomment-985838251